# Having iframe load after scrolling down on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a basic HTML page that has about 20+ iframes of HTML pages that was made with Adobe Edge Animate. Each page contains one animated image that lasts about 3 seconds. How can I have the iframes load/animate as I scroll down the page to view them? Right now they all load on page load and you can't see the ones at the bottom of the page animate unless you refresh the page.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Right now it is just iframes inside a table. No javascript etc because I'm not sure what to implement with that.

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2"><strong>160x600 - English/Spanish</strong></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><iframe width="160" height="600" src="2016/160x600/160x600.html"></iframe></td>
<td><iframe width="160" height="600" src="2016/160x600Spanish/160x600Spanish.html"></iframe></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the HTML pages made by Edge Animate:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edge_includes/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-10230890 { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
<script>
   AdobeEdge.loadComposition('160X600', 'EDGE-10230890', {
    scaleToFit: "none",
    centerStage: "none",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "160px",
    height: "600px"
}, {"dom":{}}, {"dom":{}});
</script>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-10230890">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: updated post to include code I have

Answer (score 3):

Iframes load when the `src` property on them is set. In order to prevent them from loading immediately, you can store the eventual `src` as a data attribute, and then set it when it is in the viewport (which I will get to in a bit):

```
<iframe src="about:blank" data-src="https://your-url-goes-here"></iframe>
```

When you're ready to make the iframe visible, do something like:

```
var iframe=$('#your-iframe-id');//or class, whatever you are using

if (iframe.data('src')){
    iframe.prop('src', iframe.data('src')).data('src', false);
}
```

This will make the iframe load and get its animation going (assuming the animation goes `onload`, I am being broad because you didn't post code).

In order to know when your iframe is visible, you can use a library like [jQuery-visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) which will let you know when a certain element is in view. You can then execute the above code when the `iframe` is in view:

```
if ($('#your-iframe-id').visible(true)) {
  // The iframe is visible, run the above code
} else {
  // The iframe is NOT visible yet, do nothing
}
```