# Have iframe load after user scrolls down page and it comes into viewport

Tags: javascript, iframe, viewport, visible

I'd like an iframe to load only when the user scrolls down the page and it comes into the viewport. This has been answered (link below) but I'm not very good with javascript and I can't work out how to combine the 2 bits of code in the answer.

Can anyone help? It would be great if someone could combine the bits of javascript for me.

Charlie

[Having iframe load after scrolling down on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322592/having-iframe-load-after-scrolling-down-on-page)

Here's what I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
title>FS checker test</title>


<style>
<!--
#iframe1 {
background-color: #ccc;
margin: 1800px 10px 10px 10px;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}
-->
</style>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<iframe id="iframe1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" data-src="http://www.mets.com"></iframe>

<script>

if ($('#iframe1').visible(true)) {
  var iframe=$('#iframe1');
  if (iframe.data('src')){
    iframe.prop('src', iframe.data('src')).data('src', false);
  } else {

  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the second bit, where it says "run the above code", put the first bit.

Comment: I tried - but it didn't work.

Comment: This is what I did:

Comment: That's a start.  The next step is to create a [mcve] showing what you tried, so we can help explain why it didn't work.  (Please do this in the question itself, rather than in comments; code in comments is basically unreadable.)

Comment: <iframe src="about:blank" data-src="https://your-url-goes-here"></iframe>

<script>

if ($('#your-iframe-id').visible(true)) {

var iframe=$('#your-iframe-id');//or class, whatever you are using

if (iframe.data('src')){
    iframe.prop('src', iframe.data('src')).data('src', false);
}

} else {

}

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Daniel. I've put the code I've come up with in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are nested incorrectly. Indenting your code will make this sort of problem much easier to spot.  Also make sure you have the browser developer tools open to the console, so you can see error messages.

This should work (provided you've also installed the jquery-visible library on the page):

```
if ($('#iframe1').visible(true)) {
  var iframe=$('#iframe1');
  if (iframe.data('src')){
    iframe.prop('src', iframe.data('src')).data('src', false);
  } else {
    // or you could omit the 'else' clause, since it's not doing anything 
  }
}
```

Comment: I still can't get this to work - I've updated the question to include the full code I have at the moment.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've linked in the jquery-visible library.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. If anyone can give me the full code I'd be really grateful.